# Prove that if $f$ is an invertible function and $g$ is an inverse, then the codomain of $g$ is equal to the domain of $f$ and vice versa

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

I am trying to show, without using the bijection properties, what is above.

Assume $f$ is an invertible function and $g$ is an inverse of $f$. For $f \circ g $ to be well defined then the image of $g$ must be a subest of the domain of $f$. For $g \circ f$ to be well defined then the image of $f$ must be a subest of the domain of $g$.

Since $f \circ g = I_{D_{g}}$ and $g \circ f = I_{D_{f}}$ then the image of $f$ is equal to the domain of $g$ and the image of $g$ is equal to the domain of $f$.

I can get as far as proving equivalence for the image but I am unsure of how to extend it to the codomain.

edit:

From above
$I_{D_{g}} \subset C_f$ and $I_{D_{f}} \subset C_g$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have figured this out. 
Let $f: X \implies Y$ and $g:Z \implies W$ We wish to show that $X = W$ and $Y = Z$

Based on the intuitive symmetry of the problem showing one or the other should be sufficient for anyone else to finish the problem.

So, we wish to show that $X = W$

Immediately we can deduce that $W \subset X$ and so if $w \in W$ then $w \in X$

Now we wish to show that $x \in X \implies x \in W$

We have $g \circ f(x) =x$ therefore x must be in $W$.

Therefore $W = X$